# Rails: update nested resource from the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, routes

I need form to update Tasks, which belong to Projects from projects view and get the error

```
No route matches [PATCH] "/projects/1/tasks/1/edit"
```

This is the list of routes available

```
project_tasks_path   GET     /projects/:project_id/tasks(.:format)   tasks#index
                     POST    /projects/:project_id/tasks(.:format)   tasks#create
new_project_task_path    GET     /projects/:project_id/tasks/new(.:format) tasks#new
edit_project_task_path   GET     /projects/:project_id/tasks/:id/edit(.:format)  tasks#edit
project_task_path    GET     /projects/:project_id/tasks/:id(.:format)   tasks#show
                     PATCH   /projects/:project_id/tasks/:id(.:format)   tasks#update
                     PUT     /projects/:project_id/tasks/:id(.:format)   tasks#update
                     DELETE  /projects/:project_id/tasks/:id(.:format)   tasks#destroy
 projects_path   GET     /projects(.:format)     projects#index
                     POST    /projects(.:format)     projects#create
 new_project_path    GET     /projects/new(.:format)     projects#new
 edit_project_path   GET     /projects/:id/edit(.:format)    projects#edit
 project_path    GET     /projects/:id(.:format)     projects#show
                     PATCH   /projects/:id(.:format)     projects#update
                     PUT     /projects/:id(.:format)     projects#update
                     DELETE  /projects/:id(.:format)     projects#destroy
 projects_update_path    POST    /projects/update(.:format)  projects#update
 projects_add_path   POST    /projects/add(.:format)     projects#add
                     POST    /projects/:project_id/tasks/:id/edit(.:format)  tasks#edit
 root_path   GET     /   projects#index
```

Here's the view code

```
<% @projects.each do |project| %>

<%= project.name %>
<% project.tasks.each do |task| %>

  <%= task.name %></p>

  <%= form_for [task.project, task], url: edit_project_task_path(task.project, task) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.submit "Update task" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to submit the request to the `edit` route.

Instead, try using `project_task_path(task.project, task)` in your `form_for`. Rails will know to send a PATCH request to the proper route.

Comment: This was the right path, actually update method wasn't fully implemented in the controller

Answer (score 0):

In the form, your URL needs to be `project_task_path(project_id: task.project, task)` because you want to use a PUT. The error here comes from the way that Rails searches through the `routes.rb`. It is looking for a PUT `edit_project_task_path` but you only have a GET.

Comment: @ChristopherEicke, <%= form_for [task.project, task], url: project_task_path(project_id: task.project, task) do |f| %> raises Syntax error syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting tASSOC

Comment: then you leave out the `project_id:` part, but anyway, @Dylan has the same answer.